# GrideView command is interfering with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, gridview, jquery-validate

I've got a GridView on the page, with a bunch of labels and a delete button for each row:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false"
            onrowdeleted="myGrid_RowDeleted" onrowdeleting="myGrid_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWhatever" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Whatever") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Whatever") %>'
                            ImageUrl="delete.gif" AlternateText="Delete"
                            CommandName="Delete" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Whenever I click that delete button jQuery validation ([jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)) is triggered on the page, and focus goes to the first invalid field.

I would expect a straight post-back since I am setting `CausesValidation="false"` for the image button. I am also trying to set ValidationGroup to some dummy value but that doesn't do any good either.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Check this: http://encosia.com/2009/11/04/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the jQuery validation initialization:

```
onsubmit: false
```